# Adjust edge weight dynamically when routing

Tags: sumo

I an currently researching on improving traffic conditions via adjusting the edge's `weight`.

The issue currently is that when generating `routes` via `DUAROUTER`, it takes in a fixed `weight` that remains constant throughout the whole routing generation.

How can I generate routes in a way such that I can adjust the `weight` midway through the generation and `DUAROUTER` should take in the new `weight` to find the shortest path?

***An rough idea of what I am trying to achieve;***

Given that the initial `weight` of the edge is its `traveltime`, if the density is too high(which suggest congestion), I would like to dynamically increase the `weight` to reflect it's *'true*' `traveltime`

Answer (score 0):

In general duarouter is capable of reading a weight file which can give (time dependent) weights (travel times) for all edges. The format is

`<additional>
   <interval begin="0" end="3600">
     <edge id="edge1" traveltime="120"/>
     ... more edges ...
   </interval>
   ... more intervals ...
</additional>`

and it is described [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Shortest_or_Optimal_Path_Routing#Custom_edge_weights). You can generate this weight file with a simulation and then employ an iterative process which runs alternating simulation and routing to achieve a user equilibrium. The tool for this is duaIterate.py and it is described [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Dynamic_User_Assignment). You can also modify this script to adapt the weight file to your wishes.

If you do not have enough time for this sometimes lengthy process, you can also use routing inside the simulation which will always the current travel time depending on the load of the edges. You can start by using the trip file which would normally go into the duarouter directly for the simulation,
so instead of
`duarouter -n net.xml -t trips.xml`
you call `sumo -n net.xml -r trips.xml`.
The details are [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Automatic_Routing). This works much faster but gives you less influence.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the suggestion thus far. I am aware of the custom `weight` files and I am currently generating them after analyzing every simulation output and using it for the next iteration simulation. The issue with this is, although it might solve some congestion on the previous simulation as highlighted as my goal, it introduced another congestion at other edge as the whole routing is based on just one fixed constant weight cost throughout.

Comment: My idea is to adjust the weight dynamically, to achieve an even spread of vehicles that utilizes the whole network available. Instead of just routing based on a fixed and constant weight

Comment: I am currently looking at TraCI/Change Edge State http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Edge_State that allows changing the weight dynamically during simulation. But I am not sure how would that work when the routes would have been generated before the simulation started, thus rendering any edge state changes useless? Unless it auto reroutes after every edge change, which doesn't seems to be stated anywhere?

Comment: You can do time triggered auto reroutes using `--device.routing.period`, see here http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Automatic_Routing or you can trigger the rerouting via TraCI

Comment: For the adjustment of `weight` do I use `adaptTraveltime(self, edgeID, time)` to set the new weight as referenced from http://www.sumo.dlr.de/daily/pydoc/traci._edge.html or do I set the edge travel time as referenced from http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Edge_State. I am confused...  Thereafter, how can I reroute those vehicles that has yet to depart via TraCI such that it now routes based on the new adjusted weight?

Comment: I have tried rerouting via `traci.vehicle.rerouteTraveltime()` and it's really slow. Like close to 40s per vehicle reroute. My network has tons of vehicles. Why is it that slow in rerouting(in comparison to when I used duarouter)? Is there a faster way to dynamically routing then?

Comment: Regarding the functions, they are both the same, just the name is different. Regarding running time, yes TraCI is sometimes slow but 40s per reroute is far too much. Can you share our scenario for review?

Comment: To test on a simplified network, I tried the following. 1 trip per second, over a time span of 1000s. My actual network is 50trips per second over 3600s. I then start `Sumo` simulation, and for every `timestep`, I query for a list of vehicles currently running in the network using `vehicleList = traci.vehicle.getIDList()`. I then reroute them by calling `traci.vehicle.rerouteTraveltime(VehID, true)`. I observed that it takes about 40-60s just to complete rerouting of 1 vehicle.

Comment: I turned to using `setEffort()` instead for my implementation of my `edge weight` as the travelTime naming is very misleading and confusing. I am a bit puzzled by the documentation though. I set the `effort` `traci.edge.setEffort("edgeA",float(350))` during `Step #3` but when I call `traci.edge.getEffort("edgeA", float(2))` it returns 350 also? Quote from documentation "Returns the effort value used for (re-)routing 
which is valid on the edge at the given time(which is the 2nd parameter)" By right, it should not return 350, but the default value, which I believe is -1?

Comment: I got it working using `traci.vehicle.rerouteEffort(VehID)`. It is much faster, at around 0.02s/veh to reroute. Just a final question to confirm that rerouting via `traci.vehicle.rerouteEffort(VehID)` is routing based on dijkstra shortest path with the effort value I set using `traci.edge.setEffort()`?

Comment: Concerning your first comment, setEffort currently sets the value for the whole simulation unless you give a specific time range so the result is correct. And yes traci.vehicle.rerouteEffort should use the efforts set for the edge unless you specified a value for the vehicle using the traci.vehicle method of the same name.